How to clear client browser cache and reflect new changes every time client open website with NGINX?
I am running Direct react build on NGINX server on GCP VM. The issue I am facing again and again is, Earlier i was opening website as example.com when I added permanent redirection with NGINX config files to www.example.com it is getting treated as new website to browser where earlier example.com was opened. In private tab website is getting redirected to www.example.com. And in some browsers normal tab with www.example.com is making cache and new changes are not getting reflected.
Here is my configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/html;  # Path to your React build folder
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;  # Redirect all non-matching routes to index.html
    }

    # Serve static files normally
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$ {
        expires 6M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}

I just want where website is working as example.com there it should redirected to www.example.com and every time client visits to website it should show latest changes.
Please help.

As a generic rule: From the server you can't expire cached content already stored in web browser caches. That can be a problem with (incorrect) permanent redirects and HSTS headers, but also with incorrect cache control headers. You can only adjust cache settings for new requests.

Rather than a parameterised redirect from http to https (with return 301 https://$host$request_uri) I would immediately redirect to to correct destination when you don't want vistors to make the unneeded intermediate step from http://example.com --> https://example.com --> https://www.example.com

i have removed. But where it was opened as example.com and cache stored it is getting opened there as example.com and no single change is getting reflected there.
